# Changed arch linux boot manager to burg....cant boot now

Tags: bootloader, arch-linux

Here is my setup (which worked fine with grub, and fine with burg when I was using Ubuntu):

```
sda1  -/boot
sda2  -/root (encrypted with LUKS
sda3  -/win7
```

I replaced grub with burg this afternoon and I know burg is installed successfully (the shiny new themes are displayed), however when I select arch I get this error:

> "ERROR: Unable to determine major/minor number of root device '/dev/mapper/MemoryCore'.   (Memory Core is the label for sda2

The burg entry for arch looks like this:

```
savedefault
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set .......image long uuid here
echo 'Loading Linux linux...'
linux /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/MemoryCore ro quiet splash
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
```

I think burg doesn't know how to decrypt sda2, but I am not sure.  I just switched to arch two days ago, so I apologize if I am missing something obvious.  Any ideas other than a reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right.  burg (which is essentially grub2) didn't include the correct line for the encrypted drive.  This page helped me fix it
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114045

```
linux    /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/mapper/your-encrypted-device cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:your-encrypted-device ro  quiet

sdaX is your root parttition (X representing the number, e.g. sda1)
your-encrypted-device: the name of your mapped device, e.g. topsecret or something smile
```